# Can I recover a Word document that was open when my computer shut off?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, file-recovery

How can I get my document on Word which was being written but not saved. The screen went dead and I turned off the computer by pushing power button. After restart the file was gone.

Is there any way to get that file back?

I am using Windows 7 on an HP computer.

Comment: What version of Word are you using? Was the file ever saved at any point? Is AutoRecovery enabled?

Comment: If Word didn't prompt you then the file is gone forever.

Answer (score 3):

When you start Word again, it should ask you if to recover the file. If it didn't, the file was never saved. It is still possible to recover the content, because Word does save every operation to log files. However, unless you are a FBI agent looking for evidence, this would be utterly impractical, because that logs are binary.